# Socket.io, Node.js and rethinkdb

Tags: node.js, sockets, rethinkdb

I am using simple application in Socket.io, Node.js and rethinkdb. In server my server.js file works about 20 min. About after 20 min my code stops.
**my server .js :**

```
var express = require('express'),
path = require('path'),
http = require('http'),
io = require('socket.io'),
r = require('rethinkdb');


var app = express();

app.configure(function() {
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser())
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

var server = http.createServer(app);
io = io.listen(server);


server.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});

var count = 0;
var say = 0;
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

count++;
socket.on('message', function(message) {
    url = message;
    //socket.join(url);
    r.connect({
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 28015
    }, function(err, conn) {
        if (err) throw err;
        r.db('test').table('online').insert({
            socket_id: socket.id,
            news_id: message
        }).run(conn, function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            r.db('test').table("online").filter({
                news_id: message
            }).count().run(conn, function(err, res) {
                if (err) throw err;
                say = res;


                console.log("connect say" + say);
                // ip = socket.handshake.address.address;              
                io.sockets.emit('pageview', {
                    'say': say,
                    'count': count,
                    'news_id': message
                });

            });

        });




    });


});



socket.on('disconnect', function() {

    var news_id = 0;
    console.log("Socket disconnected:" + socket.id);

    r.connect({
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 28015
    }, function(err, conn) {

        if (err) throw err;

        r.db('test').table("online").filter({
            socket_id: socket.id
        })("news_id").run(conn).then(function(cursor) {


            cursor.each(function(err, item) {

                news_id = item;


                r.db('test').table("online").filter({
                    socket_id: socket.id
                }).delete().run(conn, function() {

                    r.db('test').table("online").filter({
                        news_id: news_id
                    }).count().run(conn, function(err, res) {
                        if (err) throw err;
                        say = res;
                        count--;
                        console.log("disconnect say" + say);
                        io.sockets.emit('pageview', {
                            'say': say,
                            'count': count,
                            'news_id': news_id
                        });

                    });

                });


                //console.log("news_id"+news_id);




            });
        });




    });




});

});
```

**my client.js:**

```
 var socket = io.connect("http://192.168.1.198:3000");


    socket.on('connect', function () {

        console.log('Socket connected');
        socket.send(news_id);
        socket.on('pageview', function (msg) {


            if(msg.news_id == news_id)
                        {
                                //$('.count_icon').html(msg.say);
                                console.log(msg.say);

                        }


        });

    });
```

While server.js running i get this error:

```
Unhandled rejection RqlDriverError: First argument to `run` must be an open connection.
at new RqlDriverError (/root/node_modules/rethinkdb/errors.js:14:13)
at Bracket.TermBase.run (/root/node_modules/rethinkdb/ast.js:129:29)
at /home/node1/server.js:82:90
at tryCatcher (/root/node_modules/rethinkdb/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:24:31)
at Promise.errorAdapter (/root/node_modules/rethinkdb/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/nodeify.js:35:34)
at Promise._settlePromiseAt (/root/node_modules/rethinkdb/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:528:21)
at Promise._settlePromises (/root/node_modules/rethinkdb/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:646:14)
at Async._drainQueue (/root/node_modules/rethinkdb/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:177:16)
at Async._drainQueues (/root/node_modules/rethinkdb/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:187:10)
at Async.drainQueues (/root/node_modules/rethinkdb/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:15:14)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
```

Comment: Doesn't look like you're closing your database connections when you're done with them, so you may be running out of resources. Also, I would opt for using a single global connection instead of creating a new one for each message/disconnect.

Answer (score 5):

The problem seems to be that you're opening too many connections and RethinkDB might be closing some of those connections. You could add logic to close those connections every time you open them, you could use one global connection or you could use something like [rethinkdbdash](https://github.com/neumino/rethinkdbdash) that handles that for you by using a connection pool.

Here's what your code would look like using a global connection (and using promises).

```
var express = require('express'),
path = require('path'),
http = require('http'),
io = require('socket.io'),
r = require('rethinkdb');


var app = express();

app.configure(function() {
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser())
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

var server = http.createServer(app);
io = io.listen(server);

server.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});

var count = 0;
var say = 0;
r.connect({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 28015
})
.then(function (conn) {
    io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

        count++;
        socket.on('message', function(message) {
            url = message;
            //socket.join(url);
            Promise.resolve()
            .then(function() {
                return r.db('test').table('online').insert({
                    socket_id: socket.id,
                    news_id: message
                }).run(conn)
            })
            .then(function() {
                return r.db('test').table("online").filter({
                    news_id: message
                }).count().run(conn);
            })
            .then(function (res) {
                say = res;
                console.log("connect say" + say);
                io.sockets.emit('pageview', {
                    'say': say,
                    'count': count,
                    'news_id': message
                });
            });
        });

        socket.on('disconnect', function() {
            var news_id = 0;
            console.log("Socket disconnected:" + socket.id);
            Promise.resolve()
                .then(function () {
                    return r.db('test').table("online").filter({
                        socket_id: socket.id
                    })("news_id").run(conn);
                })
                .then(function (cursor) {
                    cursor.each(function(err, item) {
                        news_id = item;
                        Promise.resolve()
                            .then(function () {
                                return r.db('test').table("online").filter({
                                    socket_id: socket.id
                                }).delete().run(conn);
                            })
                            .then(function () {
                                return r.db('test').table("online").filter({
                                    news_id: news_id
                                }).count().run(conn);
                            })
                            .then(function (res) {
                                say = res;
                                count--;
                                console.log("disconnect say" + say);
                                io.sockets.emit('pageview', {
                                    'say': say,
                                    'count': count,
                                    'news_id': news_id
                                });
                            });
                    });
                });
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: thank you for reply. code is running successfully, socket connects. but, nothing happened with RethinkDB. insert, select, delete actions don't work and there is no any error. I think the problem with "promises". My node.js version is v0.12.4.

Comment: after many trying i get right result. I used [rethinkdbdash](https://github.com/neumino/rethinkdbdash) and used your code. here is my successful code:

http://fpaste.org/229204/35061381/

Comment: I had an bug in my code, where I overwrote the `conn` variable and so the connection was undefined (It's fixed now). Anyways, glad you got it to work!